# How to use priority_queue with a map filled with contents from file

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a large textfile that is filled with two arguments on each row. For example It looks something like this **(108.163.172.23 5654)**.

> - **104.146.174.11 1313**
> - **107.158.157.22 1535**
> - **108.164.150.26 1987**
> - **109.180.174.25 1601**
> - **107.176.178.32 1762**

My map and priority_queue definitions look like this.

```
map<string, int> map1; //(key, value)(108.163.172.23 1236)
priority_queue<data_pq> pq; //data_pq is a struct
```

Where data_pq is a **struct**

```
struct data_pq
{
    //needed for priority_queue

    string ip; //key
    int amount; //value

    data_pq()
    {
        ip = "";
        amount = 0;
    }

    data_pq(string ip, int amount)
    {
        this->ip = ip;
        this->amount = amount;

    }

    friend bool operator<(const data_pq& opleft, const data_pq& opright)
    {
        return opleft.amount < opright.amount; //AM I overloading properly?
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << "IP: " << ip << setw(10) << "amount: " << amount << endl;
    }
};
```

Also my

```
  void popandprint(int n) //printing and removing previous 
        {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                auto obj = pq.top();
                obj.print();
                pq.pop();
            }
        }
```

my goal is to be able to print this to console output. Basically the value **(2nd argument in textfile)** from map is sorted in a descending order from highest to lowest.

> - **map(key, value) value now sorted**
> - **108.164.150.26 1987**
> - **107.176.178.32 1762**
> - **109.180.174.25 1601**
> - **107.158.157.22 1535**
> - **104.146.174.11 1313**

I am wondering how to go about retrieving the contents from the file to the map **file2map function** and then I would maybe use emplace or push and what would the difference be? I see some people use emplace and some push for inserting. I think It could be like this but I am not sure how to implement this and how my file2map would look like.

```
for (auto it = map1.begin(); it != map1.end(); ++it)
        {
            pq.emplace(data_pq(it->first, it->second));

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file2map is simply file IO; for example:

```
map<string, int> file2map(const char* path)
{
    map<string, int> m;
    string s;
    int i;
    ifstream fin(path);
    if (fin.good())
        while(fin>>s>>i)
            m[s]=i;
    return m;
}
```

[emplace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/emplace/) takes variable arguments and passes them us the template class constructor. for example you can use `pq.emplace(it->first, it->second);` to avoid the construction of a temporary object.